# Setting OnItemClickListener from Adapter Class

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, listviewitem

I have a `ListView` in my **MainActivity.java**. The adapter for that list view is being set from The `AsyncTask` class which pulls in data from the `sqlite` database. Now I need to set the `OnItemClickListener` for the `ListView`. I have tried to set the Listener from different classes including **MainActivity** class and the class extending `ArrayAdapter` class but for some reason it's not working.

I also tried to do it from the class extending `AsyncTask` but I get a error saying that I need to set the listener from the **UI thread**

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if(s.equals(SUCCESS_FETCH_ALL)){
            mList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else if (s.equals(SUCCESS_INSERT))
            mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class));
     }
```

I have also tried to create a separate class and make it implement the Click Listener

**[The entire code is on Github](https://github.com/0xtvarun/Bunk-Confidently)**

> Below are the links for the classes that are involved in the question

- [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/0xtvarun/Bunk-Confidently/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vtewari/bunkconfidently/MainActivity.java)
- [DbWorkerTask.java](https://github.com/0xtvarun/Bunk-Confidently/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vtewari/bunkconfidently/workers/DbTaskWorker.java)
- [LectureListAdapter.java](https://github.com/0xtvarun/Bunk-Confidently/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vtewari/bunkconfidently/adapter/LectureListAdapter.java)
- [ListListener.java](https://github.com/0xtvarun/Bunk-Confidently/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vtewari/bunkconfidently/Listeners/ListListener.java)

Comment: Where is the code for setting onItemClick on the ListView? It's not clear why you want to set the listener from within the adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **LectureListAdapter**   you can set **clickListener** in `getView()`

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

           .....

        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
            // do your stuff here for onlick
         }
        });
        return row;
    }
```